# (Code First Migrations) Add column with unique key to existing table

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I want to add a new column "Email" (nvarchar) to an existing user table, default value has to be 'NULL' because there are already existing users. The column also needs an unique index and that's my problem.

The created migration always fails because all existing rows will get default value 'NULL' for "Email" column - and this is not possible with an unique index.

Question here is: Is it possible to add a new column with an unique index to an existing table? Can I feed the column with different values inside my migration so the unique index is "happy"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values

Comment: could be you need unique filtered index, and make only not null values unique. Or you need to do migration in several stages

Comment: you start off by creating the column as nullable.  Then populate all the rows with initial data.  once every row has a value you then change the column so its not null and then create your indexes.